# Visual Studio Code Venv Used Wrong Python Version

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, virtualenv

I have Python 3.4 and 3.9 installed. I chose the former through the Command Palette and then (also through the Command Palette) created a virtual environment with Venv. I create a new terminal, enter python --version, and it says 3.9 instead of 3.4.

How do I go about fixing this?

Comment: Click on the Python version in lower right corner, and it should show all of the interpreters that VSCode can see. Your .venv should be there.

Comment: @picobit It doesn't show the interpreters on my end. In the lower right, all I see is options for Tweet Feedback and Notifications

Comment: Have you installed the [**Python**](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.python) extension?

Comment: @JialeDu Yes, I have

Comment: Reinstall vscode. Have you tried my answer?

Comment: @JialeDu I reinstalled vscode. I managed to see the python version in the lower right after creating and opening a python file. I then tried creating a virtual environment as per the official documentation, and for some reason... It still uses Python 3.9 despite 3.4 being the selected interpreter

Comment: Also to note is that upon creating the environment, it activates itself when I open the directory with vscode, so activation doesn't seem to be the issue as implied in your answer

Comment: Oh, I forgot to mention... In the step where I have to pick the interpreter for venv, it strangely doesnt list python 3.4. Simply pressing Enter at that step defaults to 3.9. So I tried creating the environment all over again, but picking the interpreter through my file system. I got an undefined error that apparently came from a syntax error in the middle of the env creation

Comment: Are you familiar with python? Can you tell me what your goal is? If you have created a virtual environment, you should type `python --version` in the terminal that activates the virtual environment, so that it will display the python version of the virtual environment. If you want to specify the python version for the virtual environment, the easiest way is to use the absolute path of the python interpreter to execute the command, such as `E:\Programs\Python\Python311\python.exe -m venv E:\workspace\py12\Foldenv`.

Comment: Maybe you should read the documentation in my answer, or search for python's official documentation to read.

Comment: @JialeDu Sorry for responding so late... Yes, I'm familiar with Python, even having a fair foundation in it. My goal for the time being is to be able to create the venv through vscode with the intended Python version, in case I haven't made that clear enough. And I did indeed type in python --version in the terminal to check the version it uses.

Comment: I've managed to get the venv working by creating it through cmd instead of vscode, but that's not quite an optimal solution

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple python environments on your machine, if you have created a virtual environment, you should run these commands after activation. If you execute the python command in a terminal where the virtual environment is not activated, the displayed version will be the one configured in the system environment variable *path*.

The correct way is:

1. Create a virtual environment
2. Activate the virtual environment
3. Execute python commands

There are two ways to activate a virtual environment:

- After creating the virtual environment use the following command to activate

  ```
  .venv\scripts\activate
  ```
- Or select the virtual environment interpreter in the select interpreter panel, and
  then create a new terminal to automatically activate the environment.

  [image]

In vscode, the interpreter version you choose for python will always be displayed in the lower right corner.

[image]

See the [Environments](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments) documentation for more details.